# Meteor MongoDB expression "if" in Query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, nosql

I'm trying to create easy search engine and I'm wondering if there is a way to create conditions in query, something like :

```
Meteor.users.find({
   if(gender_given) gender:"something",
   if(name_given) name:"something"
});
```

Right now all that comes to my mind is to create variable with whole `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` collection, and then loop through whole array looking for matching records, but I'm sure this is not going to be effective.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a dynamic selector to accomplish this. For example:

```js
var selector = {};

if (gender)
  selector.gender = gender;

if (name)
  selector.name = name;

Meteor.users.find(selector);
```

Comment: Nice, that was I was thinking about! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
var result;
if (gender_given) {
  result = Meteor.users.find({
    gender:"something"
  });
} else if (name_given) {
  result = Meteor.users.find({
    name:"something"
  });
}
```

Comment: Because I want it to have multiple searching options, and not necessary all have to be given, so with 3 options there are 9 ifs, with 4 16 ifs etc.

Comment: Yeah the other answer is better, go with that one